How to change bulb base in ceiling light?
House built in 2007, I unscrewed the glass cover to change out weak lights and found out the right side is using a smaller bulb base than the one on the left. Is it an easy fix to change the right side to match the left?



Are you sure that there isn't an adapter threaded into the right socket to accommodate the smaller lamp? If so, removing it ought to restore the fixture to its original condition.

I updated the post to show the inside, I tried to see if I could remove it but couldn't, is that a removable adapter?

It looks like an adapter. After making sure that the power is off I'd try removing it. There is a small block on the inner edge (near the white wire in the top photo) that might be useful. A small screwdriver inserted across the opening may be able to engage the block and provide enough leverage to rotate the adapter. (It could bear against a plastic pen slipped down the center.) I'd also be curious about what appears to be a black wire spring. It may serve to prevent the adapter from unscrewing with the bulb. Needlenose pliers can grab the exposed end and remove it.

That looks like an adapter. If you’re willing to destroy that part of the fixture, try jamming pliers into the e12 socket (power off at the panel, of course!) and opening the pliers to get enough friction to twist counterclockwise.

Looks like there may be a wire retaining clip—see that straight piece of wire that sticks out?  Can you use pliers to work that out?

My first thought also was an adapter. However, the outside diameter of the second socket looks smaller than the other socket. The warning label clearly specifies A19 bulbs so I’d assume a previous owner replaced one of the sockets. You may want to replace the fixture.

To clarify: A19 sockets take the Edison E26 or E27 base lamps, common in North America. Almost certainly, the socket for the "candelabra" size lamp is a screw-in adapter -- remove it to fit a standard E26/27 lamp. There looks to be a spring retainer holding it in place, in the photo.
